# What is a CSS mergeFile?

Tags: html, css, missing-data

I am converting a website to a CMS. I noticed a line in the code that calls mergeFile:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
   type="text/css" href="foo/bar/style.css@mergeFile=_page.css" />
```

I can't seem to access all the CSS from this mergeFile. What is a mergeFile and how do I access it's contents?

Comment: How did you try to "access all the CSS with a call"?

Comment: What platform is this on? What CMS?

Comment: It's going to be something specific to this site – it's not a standard thing.

Comment: This looks like a call to a script on the server to combine two CSS files to prevent a second http request.

Comment: @PeeHaa bad syntax, see my edit

Comment: @Oded modx, but the original website had no CMS

Comment: @Moosman see comment to RB